# Auto-size container with fixed image where text should fill the gap

Tags: html, css

So without using Flex, how can I make this text container fill the gap of the parent, when another div (fixed image) it's already inside? Thanks in advance.

Here's the code:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Testing</title>

  <style>
      #container { width: 50%; height: 100px; margin: 0 auto; border: solid 1px #fb9494;}
      .image { height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: #d9d9d9; float: left;}
      .text { width: 100%; background-color: yellow; float: left;}

  </style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
    <div class="image">image</div>
    <div class="text">text</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to the `text` class:

```
.text { 
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
    height: 100px;
 }
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/abbts5n3/

Comment: That worked perfectly. Didn't know about calc at all. Thanks!